# Como pegar dados de um objeto e fazer operação matemática com outro objeto em C++?

Tags: c++

Tenho que calcular a distância entre dois pontos em C++ (Orientada a Objetos)

Eis o código que tenho:

```
Ponto p1(2,-3);
Ponto p2(4,5);

class Ponto
{
public:
    Ponto(int x1, int y1) : x(x1), y(y1) {}

    CalculaDist ();

private:
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 7):

Se você tem dois pontos `a = [x1, y1]`, e `b = [x2, y2]`, ao introduzir o ponto `c = [x1, y2]`, você terá um triângulo retângulo com o ângulo reto no vértice `c`. Esse triângulo tem como um dos catetos, o lado `ac`, que mede `|y2-y1|`. O outro cateto é o lado `bc`, que mede `|x2-x1|`. Calcular o tamanho desses dois catetos é fácil porque eles estão alinhados em relação a um dos eixos (um no x e o outro no y), e portanto o comprimento deles é a diferença das posições em relação ao outro eixo.

Com isso, a distância entre os pontos `a` e `b` pode ser calculada com o teorema de Pitágoras, pois o segmento `ab` é a hipotenusa desse triângulo retângulo.

Eis como fica o seu código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class Ponto {
public:
    Ponto(int x1, int y1) : x(x1), y(y1) {}

    double calcular_distancia(Ponto &outro) {
        int a = x - outro.x;
        int b = y - outro.y;
        return sqrt(a * a + b * b);
    }

    int inline get_x() {
        return x;
    }

    int inline get_y() {
        return y;
    }
private:
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main() {
    Ponto p1(2, -3);
    Ponto p2(4, 5);
    double distancia = p1.calcular_distancia(p2);
    cout << distancia;
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/vtg34V)

Answer (score 5):

Para calcular a distância entre dois pontos em um plano cartesiano aplica-se a seguinte fórmula:

[image: formula]

Com base no exemplo da sua pergunta, segue uma possível solução para o seu problema:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

class Ponto
{
    public:

        Ponto( int x, int y ) : x(x), y(y) { }

        virtual ~Ponto( void ) { }

        double CalculaDist( const Ponto& p )
        {
            int x1 = p.x - this->x;
            int y1 = p.y - this->y;

            double d = std::pow(x1, 2) + std::pow(y1, 2);
            return std::sqrt(d);
        }

    private:

        int x;
        int y;
};


int main(void)
{
    Ponto p1( 2, -3 );
    Ponto p2( 4, 5 );

    std::cout << "Distancia: " << p1.CalculaDist( p2 ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
$ ./distancia
Distancia: 8.24621
```

Answer (score 5):

Como eu suspeito que o próprio conceito de distância não ficou muito claro, deixo aqui o meu contributo, apenas como complemento às já bastante boas respostas do @VictorStafusa e do @Lacobus.

Apresento assim um diagrama que elaborei do cálculo que está a tentar efetuar e respetivas representações no plano cartesiano.

[image: gráfico]

Repare que o calculo para a linha vermelha, a distância, segue o teorema de Pitágoras, como o @VictorStafusa já indicou.

Esse é formalmente apresentado como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para o exemplo:

- `h` - hipotenusa que corresponde à distância, a linha vermelha
- `a` - cateto que corresponde à linha azul
- `b` - cateto que corresponde à linha amarela